# What is a good way to get chat messages to Android from my chat server?

Tags: android, notifications

I'm writing an application which will include a chat system.  I'm at a stage that I need to make a chat for my users. I have a server side application which is storing messages fine, but I don't know what is the best way to communicate with it from an Android device?

How can my application learn that new data has arrived with a maximum delay of, say, a second? Do I need to keep asking the server every second or is there any other way to notify the application that new messages have been sent and then call the server to get the data .

Do you have a suggestion how to structure the messages? I mean there could be lots of chats going on at the same time.

What do you think is the best way to approach this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You can read about the GMC(Google Cloud Messaging ) that is a service where when a message is sent by the user it will notify that a message is recieved without even calling for the server every n seconds to save data of course.

Comment: As is mentioned below the question title, "how to make a chat inside android app" is a bit broad and doesn't quite match your real question which is more "What is a good way to get chat messages to Android from my chat server?".  

I have submitted an edit to your question that hopefully makes it clearer and will get you better answers.  If your real question is "how to make a chat inside android app" then you might consider just linking to a slack forum or using some other external IRC or similar app.  Don't build your own chat unless you really have to.

Answer (score 7):

I searched for different ways of chatting in android, i found following ways:

- Push Notifications.
- Socket Programming.
- Using web service(Call server in background thread).
- XMPP(Not available for free).

**Push Notification:** I was using GCM Push notification, but problem with this was that, some devices getting notification very late.
**Socket Programming:** Then i went for use socket programming, I download some sample programs of socket programming but while using this i noticed in this case web service was called again and again in a thread.
So i decided last. **Using web service(Call server in background thread).** simply calling web service again and again to check new data.

I am using IntentService which runs in background, according me this is best way.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, but you should use json format for data transfer (with a parser of course) and a http library such as Volley, for good networking performance.

As for the question about getting a notification from server about new data to be downloaded, consider using [push notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) provided by Google Cloud Messaging. Just a word of advice - always have a normal, looped way of data checking while using GCM, as it tends to fail at times.